# PHP PDO update two tables

Tags: php, pdo

I want to update two tables, when I use submit form. I use this code, but update only one table. How to do to update both?

```
 $cryptpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
 $db = DB();
 $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE passrecovery SET resComplete = 'Yes' WHERE email = :email");
 $query->closeCursor();
 $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = :cryptpass WHERE email = :email");
 $query->execute(array(
  ':email' => $row['email'],
  ':cryptpass' => $cryptpass,
  ));
print_r("<div class='success'>Success</div>");
```

Comment: You forgot to `execute()` the first query.

Comment: Yes, he forgot it, but why 2 updates? It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cryptpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
 $db = DB();
 $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE passrecovery p, members m
SET p.resComplete = 'Yes', m.password = :cryptpass 
WHERE p.email = m.email and p.email = :email");
 $query->execute(array(
  ':email' => $row['email'],
  ':cryptpass' => $cryptpass,
  ));
print_r("<div class='success'>Success</div>");
```